# How to start an activity in a widget button

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have the following code so far:

```
// Login Button
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.putExtra("Source", "widgetLogin");
        PendingIntent loginPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, loginIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        returnView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_login_button_login, loginPIntent);
        return returnView;
```

However when I click on it nothing happens? I am sure I am just missing something with my intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, loginIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

into

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, loginIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```